# How to preserve Accessibility focus in List when navigating back from the next View in a NavigationView?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview

I have a `NavigationView` were a user can select a chapter in a `List` to navigate to the contents of that chapter.

The problem is that when navigating back from the text to the chapters view, `Accessibility` does not preserve focus on the selected chapter, forcing a `Voice Over` user to navigate the content list from the beginning again, which is not a good user experience.

Here is a minified example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(1..<10) { row in
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Text for chapter \(row)")) {
                  Text("Chapter \(row)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you select for example "Chapter 3" using `Voice Over` to see its contents and then navigate back to the Chapters-view, `Accessibility` focus will move back to the first element in the list. When a user has read a chapter, the natural next step is to read the next chapter. But since `Accessibility` is not preserving the selected chapter in focus, the user is forced to navigate the chapter list from the beginning every time.

How can I maintain `Accessibility` focus on "Chapter 3" when navigating back?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can Achieve this with 2 different approaches:

1.- Using AccessibilityFocusState Property Wrapper with a Boolean Type
2.- Using AccessibilityFocusState Property Wrapper by creating an Hashable Enum with types for your different list elements.

something like this should be inside your struct that copntains your views:

```
    enum FocusableViews: Hashable, Equatable {
        case itemYouWantToFocus, none
    }

    @AccessibilityFocusState var currentFocus: FocusableView?
```

then, This modifier should be added to the NavigationLink where you want to track the FocusState:

```
NavigationLink( destination: 
  Text("")
    .accessibilityFocused($currentFocus, equals: .itemYouWantToFocus)
}, Label:
{
    Text("Navigate")
})
```

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issues, or you don't know how to do it ;)

Comment: How would this work with the example I gave?

Comment: You just have to add the .accessibilityFocused Modifier, and implement what I mentioned above. Please notice that you're creating as list from 1 to 10, this list just have a Text inside, please try to use some struct model that implementds Identifiable, that way you can identify which element from inside the list you want to persist the selection.